# How to specify a threshold angle in Corner detection using OpenCV?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to get corners that are formed by two approximately perpendicular line segments, and not all the possible corners that are detected by either Shi-Tomasi or the Harris corner detectors provided in OpenCV.

Eg:

```
000000000000000110
000000000000001100
000000000000011000
000000000000110000
000000000001100000
111111111111111111
000000000000000000
000000000000000000
```

Something like the above would generate a corner as required - the two lines are close enough to being perpendicular.

However, here's what I'm trying to avoid:

```
000000000000000000
000000000000001111
000000000011110000
111111111100000000
000000000000000000
```

Here the lines are definitely not nearly-perpendicular however there's no argument to specify a threshold angle to the detectors. Is there any way to implement this using OpenCV? If not, then resources that point how to code one from scratch using C/C++ would be really helpful.

**FURTHER DETAILS:**
This came up while trying to implement offline sketch interpretation - the "Corner Detection" portion from this [paper](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/lapis/projects/udsi/aaai04.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Are there many such lines/corners in your image?  One thing I can think of is to try a [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) to get all the lines first, then examine the angles between line pairs.

Comment: That i tried out, however there are many cases of a straight line segment joining a circle at right angles (my exact goal is not that in the linked paper)

Comment: That paper is doing pretty much what I described -- find straight lines, then find corners where the lines meet by examining the angle between them (the difference is they're using Canny edge detection and contours to find straight lines).  What are you actually trying to do -- implement the approach in the paper, or do things your own way?

Comment: the latter actually. trying to modify the existing minimum corner eigenvalue Corner detectors which are more robust - including an angle clause in the program. still working on that one. Hough in this case is giving too many false positives, or broken lines.